# Download de imagem que pede senha

Tags: bug, imagem, segurança

Esbarrei com essa pergunta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/184885/132

Ao abri-la no Firefox, a seguinte mensagem apareceu:

[image: Pedindo senha]

Obviamente, isso me pareceu ser extremamente suspeito. Olhando o código-fonte da questão, me pareceu ser um acidente, onde o usuário linkou para figuras que estão em algum servidor que requer autenticação.

Tentei pegar o link e colocá-lo aqui:

> [Isto é um link para uma figura http://uniaodigitalinfo.esy.es/livros/Add.png](http://uniaodigitalinfo.esy.es/livros/Add.png)

O link acima aparece como uma imagem quebrada no Chrome e como um texto normal no Firefox.

Se você estiver abrindo esta página no Firefox, uma mensagem como a que está acima deve aparecer. O Chrome parece não ter esse problema.

Particularmente, eu considero isso como uma falha de segurança da SE que abre caminho para ataques de phishing.

Pesquisando no metão, achei isso: [How does StackOverflow handle images from external URLs?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/115178/176034)

O que fazer em casos como esses? O que a SE acha disso?

Comment: O mesmo está a acontecer no "Sandbox (ou “chiqueirinho”) de formatação", depois da resposta que você colocou. O melhor seria remover o link nela.

Comment: @ramaral O que demonstra que isso é grave, mesmo se a resposta for deletada, usuários que podem ver respostas deletadas ainda são alvos do ataque. No entanto, vou editar aquela resposta ali para não abusar dos nossos usuários.

Comment: O problema é que para proteger o usuário do site, ou a imagem teria que ser "importada" automaticamente (o que eu acho uma boa, afinal não quebraria com o tempo) mas pesaria pro imgur. A outra seria um proxy, o que gastaria banda (em dobro) ao acessar os recursos. No meu ver, o autoimport para o imgur seria o melhor.

Comment: Relacionado? http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291947/176034

Comment: Ia comentar isso, a migração pra imgur é exatamente o que eu comentei anteriormente. Me parece uma ótima decisão. "Se a rede fosse minha" eu faria pra todas, não apenas para as sem https.